# How to add a word at a end of a cell on multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a table which has a list of stations and on multiple columns it does not have the specific word 'station' at the end of each cell. 
How would I add the word 'station' to the end of the line.

```
RailwayID | Railway Name

1.         | YATE
3.         | York
```

E.g. `YATE` should update to `YATE STATION`, 
`York` should update to `York station`.

I have use this query to find all the station without the word station in the Cell

`select RailwayName from RailwayStations where RailwayName NOT LIKE '%Station%'`

Comment: pls. choose any one of MySQL and SQL-Server which is different.

Comment: Sunil, I down-voted your question because you couldn't even be bothered to tell us the correct DBMS you were using.

Comment: He has, the tag says sql-server-2008

Comment: Initially it said MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
FOR MYSQL :
update tablename set Railway_Name= CONCAT(Railway_Name,' station')
where Railway_Name NOT LIKE '%Station%'
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/RKYV34919)  here

```
FOR SQL 2008

update tablename set Railway_Name = Railway_Name+' station'
where Railway_Name NOT LIKE '%Station%'
```

Comment: That doesn't handle the case matching that Sunil described in his example, and if [Railway Name] already contains 'station' then this will put it in twice.  E.g. 'DUNKIRK STATION' would become 'DUNKIRK STATION station'.

Comment: I have updated my edit by I can't use CONCAT AS I AM USING SQL 2008 :(

Comment: @Sunil at the time that Mr. Bhosale posted his answer your question was tagged as MySQL, not MS-SQL.  No need to shout.

Answer (score 0):

Simply concatenate ' station' to the column, if it's not already there.

```
update tablename
set RailwayName = RailwayName + ' STATION'
where UPPER(RailwayName) not like '% STATION%'
```

Do you expect same case? I.e. STATION if YATE, and station if York?

```
update tablename
set RailwayName = RailwayName + 
                         case when RailwayName = UPPER(RailwayName) then ' STATION'
                              else ' station'
                         end
where UPPER(RailwayName) not like '% STATION%'
```

Comment: The string comparison in your case statement is going to return true every time for SQL Server. You would need to add `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` after the comparison to enforce case sensitive string comparison.

Comment: I have updated my edit by I can't use CONCAT AS I AM USING SQL 2008 :(

Comment: Then you can use SQL Server's `+` for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

This works on SQL2008

```
DECLARE @tableName TABLE (RailwayName NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tableName
    (RailwayName) VALUES (N'YORK'),(N'Leeds'),(N'Bradford station'),(N'DEWSBURY STATION') 
SELECT * FROM @tableName

update @tableName
set RailwayName = RailwayName + 
                    CASE
                        WHEN RailwayName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = UPPER(RailwayName) 
                            THEN ' STATION'
                        ELSE
                            ' station'
                     END
WHERE UPPER(RailwayName) NOT LIKE '% STATION%'

SELECT * FROM @tableName
```